# JavaScript: I passed in a list, tried to access an index, it says the variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote the following to test out drawing on a canvas:

```js
function draw3(cg, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke(cg);
}
function march(i, gl, ct) {
  draw3(gl[i], ct);
  setTimeout(march((i+1)%2), 40);
}
function draw3main() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var coolGuy = new Path2D("M10 10 h 50 v 50 h -50 Z");
  var coolGuy2 = new Path2D("M11 11 h 50 v 50 h -50 Z");
  var guysList = [coolGuy, coolGuy2];

  march(0, guysList, ctx);
}
```

When I run it nothing gets drawn and the browser console reports "gl" undefined on the line in the `march` function which reads `draw3(gl[i], ct);`.  But it's an argument passed into the function, so it should be defined.  Can't trace the bug, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
setTimeout(march((i+1)%2), 40);
```

to

```
setTimeout(march, 40, (i + 1) % gl.length, gl, ct);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function() {
  march((i + 1) % gl.length, gl, ct);
}, 40);
```

Right now you're immediately invoking `march()` with only one parameter `(i+1)%2`.

---

All together, it looks like this:

```js
function draw3(cg, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke(cg);
}

function march(i, gl, ct) {
  draw3(gl[i], ct);
  setTimeout(march, 40, (i + 1) % gl.length, gl, ct);
}

function draw3main() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var coolGuy = new Path2D("M10 10 h 50 v 50 h -50 Z");
  var coolGuy2 = new Path2D("M11 11 h 50 v 50 h -50 Z");
  var guysList = [coolGuy, coolGuy2];

  march(0, guysList, ctx);
}

draw3main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas3" width="72" height="72"></canvas>
```